# Error en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en *Android Studio* pero al momento de ejecutarla por el emulador me esta dando el siguiente error:

> Error: cannot find symbol variable fab

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(
            view,
            "Replace with your own action",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
        ).setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SOes! Si no se puede encontrar una variable aun que `R` fue creado correctamente significa que el `ìd` no esta bien definido en el layout de esta  vista. Puedes compartir el `layout` que usas y el código donde defines el `layout`de la vista padre?

Comment: Ese error se debe a que el _IDE_ no encuentra la definición del tipo `FloatingActionButton`. Deberías revisar tus `import`, posiblemente no la has importado correctamente.

Comment: Simplemente agrega el elemento con el id fab  dentro de tu layout 
 @FABIANAGUILAR

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema es que no defines la variable, debería hacer algo así:

```
// Aquí debes definir la variable, así:
FloatingActionButton fab1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Y en tu `layout`:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        fab:fab_label="Nombre"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        android:clickable="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Como dice *UserNameYo*, debes declarar tu variable control. Además, estoy de acuerdo en que te faltan añadir bien tus `import`. Te recomiendo la siguiente forma:

1. Añade la siguiente línea en tu archivo **.gradle** en *Android Studio* en la parte de `dependencies`.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

2. Al momento en que agregas esta línea en la parte superior del código en el archivo saldrá una línea amarilla y a tu derecha un enlace que dirá ***Sync Now***. Tu proyecto se sincronizará, esperas a que termine.
3. Por último añades en tu *Layout* lo siguiente:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

También antes de ejecutar tu aplicación puedes observar el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema es que dentro del layout que cargas por medio de `setContentView()` que generalmente es `activity_main.xml`, no existe un elemento con id `fab`.** Asegura estas cargando el layout contenedor.

Agregalo para que puedas encontrar una referencia del `FloatingActionButton`.